# If sinx = 4/5 and cosx = 3/5 find the exact values of tan2x

Tags: trigonometry

Please show me the steps to completing this question.

$$\sin x = \frac45 \\ \cos x = \frac35$$

What is the value of $\tan(2x)$?

Thanks.

Comment: The double-angle formula for tangent would probably be helpful. Do you know it?

Comment: @MikePierce It is not provided in my textbook, so it probably wants me to solve it without it.

Comment: Well then what section of your textbook are you in? (how should you approach solving this)

Comment: @MikePierce It only provided me with the double-angle formula of sin2x and cos2x.

Comment: Do you recall that $\tan(x) = \sin(x)\;/\cos(x)$? You can do the same thing if there is a $2$ there. So $\tan(2x) = \sin(2x)\;/\cos(2x)$. Does this help?

Comment: @MikePierce Gotcha :D

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\tan(2x)&=\frac{\sin2x}{\cos{2x}} \\
&=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}\\
&=\frac{2\cdot\frac45\cdot\frac35}{\left(\frac35\right)^2-\left(\frac45\right)^2}\\
&=-\frac{24}7
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

First, remember that: $$\forall (a,b)\in\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbb{Z}\right)^2,\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}.$$
Therefore, one gets: $$\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)^2}.$$
Besides, one has: $$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{4}{3}.$$
Finally, one has: $$\tan(2x)=-\frac{24}{7}.$$

Comment: While this is correct, I find its much easier to just remember the sine/cosine  sum or double angle identites and derive this from there. The tan double angle identity comes up far less often than the other two.